# iOS 7 Custom Keyboard & Current Font -- Can they be linked?

Tags: ios, fonts, uikeyboard

Is there a way for an app to have a custom keyboard reflect the currently selected font?

For instance: You are a crazy/drunk person, and want to type up a document using the font Comic Sans.  Upon selecting the font you want to use, the letters on the keyboard appear in that font.

Can this be done?

Would it require a custom keyboard for each available font in the app?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you have to create a one custom keyboard mimicking the default keyboard. Since you will have access to the keys of your custom keyboard you can change the font for the keys.

So you would need only one custom keyboard and a way to change the font for the keys in the keyboard.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, I can put whatever font I want on a custom keyboard without issue.  Yes?  The question of whether or not I can change the font of said keyboard on the fly remains, though...

Comment: YES. You can change the font of custom keyboard keys. It is as simple as changing the font of the UIButtons(the keys). Since it is custom keyboard (essentially a custom view) you have full control over it . you can change it on the fly.

Comment: Thank you.  Are there any examples of this that you could point me to?  I've never seen an app do this, but it's such a simple idea that I'd assume it exists out there, somewhere. Never found it in the few dozen or so writing apps I've checked out...

Comment: There are many examples for implementing custom keyboard out there. The rest is just logic.